# add an input field in splashscreen using cordova spalshscreen pulgin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

is there any  way to implement custom  make Splash screen in ionic which have multiple logo  and an input field on splash screen. i am using Cordova splash screen plugin for the the above implementation

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic splash screen without a [cordova-plugin-splashscreen plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen). In this example the splash screen is removed using [afterEnter view event](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/). The [idea](http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/) is simple, show a fixed overlay container over a rest of the content.

Add this DIV to your **HTML** page. Inside that DIV you have logo and input fields.

```
    <div id="custom-splashscreen">
  <div class="item item-image">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fGX23IjV0xs/VcRc4TLU_fI/AAAAAAAAAKk/ys3cyQz6fQc/s1600/download.jpg">
  </div>
   <div class="card">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
   <div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <textarea placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Add this to **css/style.css**. Customize CSS depending on what you want to achieve.

```
#custom-splashscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #771313;
}
#custom-splashscreen .item-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #771313;
}
```

Add this to your **controller** if you want that splash screen disappear after a specified number of seconds. Considering that you have input fields I guess you do not want splash screen to disappears. In controller you can put whatever you want. For example, a splash screen will be removed after a user clicks on the button.

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("custom-splashscreen").style.display = "none";
        }, 3000);
    })
```

Splash screen should look like this. As you can see it have logo and input fields.

[image]

P.S. For the purposes of development add [CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to Chrome and enable it while you work on app.

Comment: I try this but the problem is it shows white screen for few second in android and in ios its getting cordova default screen then only it appears that div..

Comment: Inside `<div id="custom-overlay">` you can put input field and style it with "custom-overlay" ID. Before that you can `remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen`. I'll try to make a demo later.